# Div Overlay Not Working in Firefox and Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one Div overlay on other. It works perfect in Chrome but does not show in Firefox and explorer

My code is

JS

```
  var $card = $("<div></div>").css({
position: "absolute",
width: "100%",
height: "100%",
top: 0,
left: 0,
opacity : 0.8,
z-index:20000,
background: "#ccc url(../images/loader2.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%"
}).appendTo($(".tile").css("position", "relative"));


setTimeout(function(){
$card.remove();
}, 5000);
```

Html

```
<div class="tile">
My code
</div>
```

CSS for class tile

```
div.tile {
background: url('../images/tiles-min.png');
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
padding:0.2em 0.2em;
    width:70%;
    height: 550px;
    display: table;
 }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include all of your code (html,css,js)? Only one element here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the W3s

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

To set multiple CSS properties, the syntax is:

```
css({"propertyname":"value","propertyname":"value",...});
```

you are missing "" in your property name.

And the issue with firefox can be resolved by adding display:table-cell.

```
var $card = $("<div>\</div>").css({
"position": "absolute",
"width": "100%",
"height": "100%",
"top": 0,
"left": 0,
"opacity" : 0.8,
"z-index":20000,
"display":"table-cell",
"background": "#ccc url(../images/loader2.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%"
}).appendTo($(".tile").css("position", "relative"));
```

div.tile has a display table hence  you need to to give display:table-cell to its children.

Comment: changed as per your advice.... But no success in firefox and explorer  your snippet work ok but my code not....

Comment: @john : in that case there must be some other part of code which is breaking it. Could you create a fiddle/plunker with you full code and replicate it?

Comment: Fiddle works fine which means some problem in code but this problem is for only Firefox and Explorer ... How i can check what causes issue in 2 browsers and not in one

Comment: @john is there any additional css you are applying. Few CSS properties works differently in different browser. I could help but need to see the full code for that

Comment: How I can show code, plz guide me and thanx for such kind gesture

Comment: if its not some office project work , you can share the zipped code using dropbox

Comment: display: table;   in .tile div {   seems to be causing issue but if i remove it then no image comes as per code

Comment: @john : updated the answer, you almost got it , you should not remove it but change it to table-cell.

Comment: Thnx for your great help .... can you plz remove my domain name from your answer plz

Comment: @john : NP :) you are welcome, removed the fiddle link as well

Comment: You saved my life on this issue.... once issue coming after this change is text-align:center was showing correctly inside table in enter now it has gone to top left corner....is it due to cell position, how to correct it

Comment: is that behavior visible on fiddle ? i did not get the issue properly

Comment: Issue seems to be solved by removing display:table;  will it be correct approach in .tile div {...